# R: Merge list of tables generated with "by" and add identifiers

Tags: r, data.table, rbind, factors

Here is a sample code to generate some y values for various test conditions and repeated tests.

```
library(data.table)
headings = seq(0,180,30)
spds=c(5,10,20,30)
tests=seq(5)
ts=seq(30*60)

dt <- data.table(hd = rep(headings,each=length(spds)*length(tests)*length(ts)),
                 spd = rep(spds,each=length(tests)*length(ts)),
                 test = rep(tests,each=length(ts)),
                 t = ts/60
                 )
set.seed(1)
dt$y <- with(dt, ((spd/22)^2 * (sin(pi/180*t) + 
                  runif(nrow(dt),-1,1)) * runif(nrow(dt))))
```

The data for each test needs some processing, and returns a table of values.  Here is a simple function to return the index, time, and y values in a range.

```
findGood<-function(x,ylim) {
  gt <- which(ylim[1] <= x$y & x$y <= ylim[2])
  dt <- data.table(indx=gt, t=x$t[gt], y=x$y[gt])
  return(dt)
}
```

Use "by" to loop over the test conditions and repeated points, generates a list of results for each combination of test conditions.

```
ylim=c(.3,.45)
t_for_good_y <- by(dt[,c('t','y'),with=FALSE],
                   dt[,c('hd','spd','test'),with=FALSE],
                   findGood,ylim)
```

The following converts the results back into a data table. However, the table does not contain the condition values (hd, spd, test)

```
tg <- rbindlist(t_for_good_y)
```

How to convert the list t_for_good_y into a data table but add columns for the conditions that each list item represents (hd, spd, and test in this example)

One possible approach would make use of dimnames

```
dn <- dimnames(t_for_good_y)
```

dn contains the names and values for the indices of the list

```
R> str(dn)
List of 3
 $ hd  : chr [1:7] "0" "30" "60" "90" ...
 $ spd : chr [1:4] "5" "10" "20" "30"
 $ test: chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
R> print(dn)
$hd
[1] "0"   "30"  "60"  "90"  "120" "150" "180"    
$spd
[1] "5"  "10" "20" "30"    
$test
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
R> names(dn)
[1] "hd"   "spd"  "test"
```

Comment: @Arun, I need to evaluate a function by group for data that is in a data table.  I thought "by" was the way to do that.  I have numerous cases where function foo processes the time history for a single run id, but the data has been stored by condition and run id's.  In the example above, the function findGood takes the time history for one run, along with the limits.  "by" is used to evaluate the data table dt that contains a large number of runs for various configurations.

Comment: I should mention the function findGood returns a variable number of rows, including zero.